# Ionic how to use js code to close cordova plugin view

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I have a Ionic Datepicker plugin in one view. When the app receive a notification message, it will jump to another view, but the datapicker view is still here. So I want to close the datepicker view when I click the notification message.
Bug how to achieve the goal?

**[Edit]**

I made a cordova plugin , which can select mul-images from my phone. When I select mul-image, if there is a notification message, like the following image, and I click this message, the plugin's view is still here, but I would like close the plugin view after I click the message.
[image]

[image]

Comment: always add relevant code when you ask questions.

Comment: Please see the editing infor.